# how to calculate latency in check phase using the array declared in run phase?

Tags: arrays, uvm

iam trying to capture the time in uvm run phase and do the latency  calculation in uvm check phase latency = end time - start time.
can you give me an idea how may  i do it? Both the start and end time have respective conditions to be captured in array during simulation for every cycle and that array need to be used in check phase for calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches to pass the arrays to check_phase:

1. If you need start_time and end_time information in check_phase of the same component, you can declare both the arrays as the class variables instead of declaring inside run_phase and access it to check_phase
2. If you need it in some other component, then you can pass it using uvm_config_db set method once both the arrays are populated with the required information

Instead of passing the start time and end time arrays, you can calculate latency in run_phase and pass an array having the latency information to check_phase using either of the above 2 approaches.

Comment: can you tell me how can i pass the latency array information to check phase if i use the 1st approach ?

Comment: [1] declare an array inside the class (let's say real latency[$]), [2]Update this array in run_phase as per the start and end simulation time per packet [3] once all the packets are driven/sampled, this latency array will have the latency information per packet that you can directly use in the check_phase

Comment: so can i use like this latency [$] = endtime[ n] - starttime[n]?

Comment: so if i need to display the latency information in check phase can i give like this : $display('latency : %d", latency[$]);

Comment: [1] at the end of each packet, you can capture latency as, latency.push_back($realtime - start_time); // In this case you don't need end_time variable as the $realtime is indicating the simulation time at that instant.

Comment: Regarding printing the latency info, the $display you have shown prints the last element of a latency queue. If you want to print the complete latency array then change the format specifier from %d to %p and remove [$] from argument. As this is UVM, you should avoid $display and use uvm_info

Comment: you can also iterate through latency queue to print all the elements one by one.

Comment: is there any way to do this just by using array and not using queue? also it is important to capture end_time in an array  because both start and end time have respective conditions as both are based on packets

Comment: function void run_phase;  int fd ;  time start []; time end[]; int n =0;                                                                        fd = $fopen("file.txt","w");                                                                                           
  fork begin forever begin  @posedge(start_clk); if(start time conditon)                  start[n] =$time; end end end                                                                  begin forever begin @posedge_end_clk); if(end time condtion) end[n]= $time; end end end n++; endfunction

Comment: this is my pseudo code.  iam unable to write it in line wise manner. here my end time is only is printing . the output is like this : end[0]= [0];. what could be the mistake?